# Ignore preview click when using AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, web-deployment, msdeploy

I have the following target setup in my csproj file:

```
<Target Name="MyPublishNotification" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
    <Exec Command="c:\SendEmail.cmd $(PublishProfileName)" />
</Target>
```

This works and sends an email when I click the Publish button in the Publish Web dialog. However, if I click the Preview button in the Publish Web dialog, that also sends an email. I need to not send notifications that the website was updated on the Preview click, just the Publish click.

Is there a way to detect when that target is hit with Preview versus Publish?

Comment: Running with verbose msbuild logging should let you figure out the difference.

Comment: I attempted to reproduce and wasn't able to.  Can you provide a working sample?